# Python Extracting strings from multiple lines of strings

Tags: python, string, indexing, extract, fasta

I would like to extract strings from input file like the below:

```
>a11
UCUUUGGUUAUCUAGCUGUAUGA
>a11
UCUUUGGUUAUCUAGCUGUAUGA
>b22
UGGUCGACCAGUUGGAAAGUAAU
>b22
ACUUCACCUGGUCCACUAGCCGU
>b22
AGGUUGUCUGUGAUGAGUUCG
>t33
UUAAUGCUAAUCGUGAUAGGGGU
>t33
CAGUAACAAAGAUUCAUCCUUGU
```

The line starts with ">" is a header and the line below is a sequence.

I would like to extract the sequences with header only strats with ">b22"

This is my code which do not give the properl answer.

```
def extractData():
    filename = ("data.txt")
    infile = open(filename,'r')

    for x in infile.readlines():
        x = x.strip()
        if x.startswith(">"):
            header = x
        else:
            sequence = x
        if header.startswith(">b22"):
            print(header, sequence)
    infile.close()

extractData()
```

It gives result like this:

```
>b22 UCUUUGGUUAUCUAGCUGUAUGA
>b22 UGGUCGACCAGUUGGAAAGUAAU
>b22 UGGUCGACCAGUUGGAAAGUAAU
>b22 ACUUCACCUGGUCCACUAGCCGU
>b22 ACUUCACCUGGUCCACUAGCCGU
>b22 AGGUUGUCUGUGAUGAGUUCG
```

But, my expected result is like this:

```
>b22 UGGUCGACCAGUUGGAAAGUAAU
>b22 ACUUCACCUGGUCCACUAGCCGU
>b22 AGGUUGUCUGUGAUGAGUUCG
```

Can somebody fix this please? What is the matter and what should I imply to get the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor changes in your code:

```
def extractData():
    filename = ("data.txt")
    infile = open(filename,'r')

    for x in infile.readlines():
        x = x.strip()
        if x.startswith(">"):
            header = x
        else:
            sequence = x
            if header.startswith(">b22"):
                print(header, sequence)
                header = ''


    infile.close()

extractData()
```

Btw, you can use debugger to identify what is wrong with the flow of program. If you are new to Python then I would recommend using Eclipse with Pydev plugin for interactive debugging. [Link for Tutorial on Pydev in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Python/article.html)

Having said that, issue appears because  `if header.startswith(">b22")` is being evaluated for each line parsed from file. When you move it inside `else` block it will only be evaluated after you are done parsing sequence (and it does not evaluate for `header` lines, obviously).

Comment: Great, but it doesnt work with the line `header = ''`. If I erase it, then it works. Why give the header null? Thank you @chandan

Comment: fixed the problem. once the header was used with sequence i.e. `print(header, sequence)` then it should be safe to set it to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach:

```
>>> with open('data.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         if line.startswith('>b22'):
...             print('{0} {1}'.format(line.strip(), next(f).strip()))
...
>b22 UGGUCGACCAGUUGGAAAGUAAU
>b22 ACUUCACCUGGUCCACUAGCCGU
>b22 AGGUUGUCUGUGAUGAGUUCG
```

Since the file can be iterated over, when you reach the line with `>b22`, you can use `next()` to read the next line.